# Problems with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At this moment I am a bloody beginner in Jquery, but the following code based on api.jquery.com in that case this should work:

---

```
<a class="btindex">Startseite</a>
```

---

```
$('.btindex').click(function(){$(this).attr('href','index.html')});
$('.btindex').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).css('background-color':'#f2ab1e')});
$('.btindex').on('mouseout',function(){$(this).css('background-color':'#f0c911')});
```

---

I also write them in one, because it is more clear to me, but, nevertheless, here is the code:

---

```
$('.btindex').click(function(){$(this).attr('href','index.html')}).on('mouseover',function(){$(this).css('background-color':'#f2ab1e')}).on('mouseout',function(){$(this).css('background-color':'#f0c911')});
```

---

Also it isn't necessary in this case here is the css file:

---

```
.btindex{
cursor: pointer;
background-color:#f0c911;
border:1px solid #e65f44;
color:#c92200;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:italic;
font-size: 150%;
height:10%;
line-height:250%;
padding: auto;
position: fixed;
visibility: hidden;
width:22%;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}
```

I hope for quick answers and that the script explains itself, if not I will answer for sure. In any case I build a fiddle as support [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hbnk/) :)

Comment: Syntax Error: `css('background-color':'#f2ab1e')` should be `css({'background-color':'#f2ab1e'})` (2 lines)

Comment: Whenever things don't work as planned, check your browser console. Its quite a life saver.

Comment: or `css('background-color','#f2ab1e')`

Comment: @myolli4 in most common browsers hitting F12 will bring up a panel. Click Console in that panel. Any errors should appear there.

Comment: far simpler and cleaner to just toggle classes.... then there's no inline style to revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally easier to refrain from setting inline style using `css()` and simply adding and removing classes to control style

If you know you have to revert back to original state this takes less time to set up with css rules than to add the JS needed to reset back to original css property values

CSS

```
.btindex.hovered{
  background-color:#f2ab1e;
}
```

JS

```
$('.btindex').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

`hover()` with only one callback will cover both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Answer (score 2):

You have colons where you should have commas - it should be:

```
$('.btindex').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).css('background-color','#f2ab1e')});
$('.btindex').on('mouseout',function(){$(this).css('background-color','#f0c911')});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hbnk/2/

or you can pass properties in an object to `css()`, being careful to use camelcase for the property names (e.g. `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`):

```
$('.btindex').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).css({backgroundColor:'#f2ab1e'})});
$('.btindex').on('mouseout',function(){$(this).css({backgroundColor:'#f0c911'})});
```

Comment: To elaborate, you can use colons in `css()` but only when you pass an object rather than a pair, which you would do when you have more than one style attribute to add (though I always use this syntax). e.g. `.css({backgroundColor: '#f2ab1e', width: '210px'})`. Notice the braces `{}` and also notice that you need the attributes to be in camelCase, i.e. background-colour => backgroundColor.

Comment: Ok you added that! +1

Comment: And then I fixed the camelcase :)

Comment: Yes I was going to comment. You don't actually need to use delimiters on the names, but it works both ways. The only exception I know of is when you set the properties of an element, e.g. `$('<div>, {id: "some_id", class: "classname"});` the `class` breaks IE, so it needs delimiters there. I avoid having to break that standard (of not using them) with `$('<div>, {id: "some_id"}).addClass("classname");` I've really gone offtopic.

Comment: @myolli4 either use `css(x,y)` (comma, no braces) or use `css({x:y})` (colon, with braces) - you've changed it to `css({x,y})`, which is an error. Changing your commas to colons works: http://jsfiddle.net/8Hbnk/6/